Parsing an Apache Log File
I have an Apache log file that looks like this:
64.242.88.10 - - [08/Mar/2004:07:56:34 -0800] "GET /twiki/bin/search/Main/SearchResult?scope=text&regex=on&search=Web%20*Index[^A-Za-z] HTTP/1.1" 200 4163

64.242.88.10 - - [08/Mar/2004:08:04:46 -0800] "GET /SpamAssassin.html HTTP/1.1" 200 7368
p5083cd5d.dip0.t-ipconnect.de - - [08/Mar/2004:08:09:32 -0800] "GET /SpamAssassin.html HTTP/1.0" 200 7368

64.242.88.10 - - [08/Mar/2004:08:12:50 -0800] "GET /twiki/bin/view/TWiki/ChangePassword?rev=r1.6 HTTP/1.1" 200 5181

64.242.88.10 - - [08/Mar/2004:08:14:15 -0800] "GET /twiki/bin/edit/TWiki/HaroldGottschalk?t=1078717948 HTTP/1.1" 401 12846

64.242.88.10 - - [08/Mar/2004:08:15:21 -0800] "GET /twiki/bin/edit/Main/Expand_owner_alias?topicparent=Main.ConfigurationVariables HTTP/1.1" 401 12846

I'm trying to get the total bytes (last sequence of digits at the end of every line) of every line and add them up to get the total bytes transmitted
My code looks like this:
static String logEntryFormat = "^(\\S+) (\\S+) (\\S+) \\\[(.*?)\\\] "(.*?)" (\\S+) (\\S+)( "(.*?)" "(.*?)")?";

public static void countTotalBytes() throws IOException {

    // First read file into an arrayList
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(accessLog);
    ArrayList\<String\> stringList = new ArrayList\<String\>();
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
    stringList.add(scanner.nextLine());

    scanner.close();

    //Convert to string
    String listString = String.join(" ", stringList);

    Pattern findBytes = Pattern.compile(logEntryFormat);
    Matcher matchBytes = findBytes.matcher(listString);

    // Test
    if(matchBytes.matches()) {
    System.out.println(matchBytes.group(7));
    }
}

I eventually want to grab this value and convert it into an int, and then calculate the total. However in my output, I am only receiving the byte value of "7368".
I'm not sure if I am approaching this all wrong but I've been stuck at this for hours.

If all you want is the last set of digits, then why is your regex more complicated than /(\d*)$/?  In fact, why use a regex at all?   Just find the last non-digit on the line and convert from there on.

Since the goal of the method countTotalBytes() is to sum up all byte values located at the end of each file data line, perhaps it should return that result, for example: int totalBytes = countTotalBytes("LogFile.log");. Now you can do whatever you like with totalBytes.
Also, you really don't need to load the file into an ArrayList to carry out this task. Just sum the byte values as you read the file and return the total once the file has been completely read.
Here is an example:
public static long countTotalBytes(String accessLog) throws IOException {
    int totalByteCount = 0;
    // Try With Resources used here to auto-close the reader:
    try (Scanner reader = new Scanner(new File(accessLog))) {
        String line;
        while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
            line = reader.nextLine().trim();
            // Skip IF current line is blank:
            if (!line.isEmpty()) {
                // Split the data line based on a whitespace delimiter (one or more):
                String[] lineParts = line.split("\\s+");
                /* Get the bytes value from the end of the data line:
                   It would be the last element in the above generated
                   array:                    */
                String numBytes = lineParts[lineParts.length - 1];
                /* Is the numerical value we pulled out a string representation
                   of a signed or unsigned integer value. If so, convert it to 
                   a Integer data type and add it to totalByteCount:        */
                if (numBytes.matches("-?\\d+")) {
                    totalByteCount += Integer.parseInt(numBytes);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return totalByteCount;
}

To use the above method:
try {
    System.out.println(countTotalBytes("AccessLog.log"));
}
catch (IOException ex) {
    System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
}

The console window should display:  49772 based on the data file information you provided.
